# Trying to get dropdown box that then open up the next dropdown. there are 3 in all

Tags: dropdown

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <span class="text-danger">*</span> Birthplace:
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Region must be a number." data-val-required="Please select Region" id="BRegionId" name="BRegionId">
                <option value="">Select Region</option>
                <option value="1">Region I - Ilocos</option>
                <option value="2">Region II - Cagayan Valley</option>
                <option value="3">Region III - Central Luzon</option>
                <option value="4">Region IVA - CALABARZON</option>
            </select>
            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="BRegionId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Province must be a number." data-val-required="Please select Province / District" id="BProvinceId" name="BProvinceId">
                <option value="">--------</option>
            </select>
            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="BProvinceId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field City/Municipality must be a number." data-val-required="Please select City/Municipality" id="BCityId" name="BCityId">
                <option value="">--------</option>
            </select>
            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="BCityId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
```

I am new to this VBA (Access 2007) to HTML (IE) side of things (it is not my profession but say hobby) and I am making most things work from reading through different posts, but one thing has got me stuck for numerous days.
The above code is part of an online form of which I have filled all the boxes except for three (3) dropdown boxes of which you need to FIRST dropdown and select the first selection which then changes the SECOND dropdown (or makes it True), then you make second selection which then changes the THIRD dropdown (or makes it TRUE), then you make the final selection.

I can focus on the first dropdown, fill in the first dropdown with data but I have tried most different 'click' arrangements I can find online and nothing seems to work.

By my understanding:

1. I need to either copy what the actual site does, (ie. somehow open the dropdown up, select the item, and then click again) or
2. Fill in the dropdown then somehow tell it (by my understanding of the code above it is looking to say it is TRUE, before it will open the next dropdown for input).

My code I am playing around with is below with a lot of the tries taken out.

```
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim MyBrowser As InternetExplorer
Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim MyURL As String

On Error GoTo Err_Clear
MyURL = "http://t2mis.tesda.gov.ph/Registration/Register"
Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
MyBrowser.Silent = True
MyBrowser.Navigate MyURL
MyBrowser.Visible = True

Do
Loop Until MyBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Set HTMLDoc = MyBrowser.Document
Err_Clear:
If Err <> 0 Then
    Err.Clear
    Resume Next
End If

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readyState = 4

HTMLDoc.All.Family_name.Value = "LASTNAME"
HTMLDoc.All.First_name.Value = "FIRSTNAME"
HTMLDoc.All.Middle_name.Value = "MIDDLENAME"

' SOME OF THE DIFFERENT CODES i HAVE BEEN TRYING TO OPEN AND SELECT 
  DROPDOWN
'Set oSELECT = MyBrowser.Document.getElementById("BRegionId")
'oSELECT.Focus
'oSELECT.selectedIndex = 11
'oSELECT.FireEvent "onchange"

'From page " 
 $('BRegionId').val('1').trigger('click').selectric('refresh'); 
  loadquote('1');"
'HTMLDoc.getElementById("BRegionId").selectedIndex = 1
'HTMLDoc.parentWindow.execScript "loadquote('1')"

'HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("form-control")(1).Click
'Set element = HTMLDoc.getElementById("BRegionId")
'HTMLDoc.getElementById("BRegionId").Click
'element.Value = "11"
'HTMLDoc.getElementById("BRegionId").Click

'Set objButton = HTMLDoc.getElementById("BRegionId")
'objButton.Focus
'objButton.Click
'HTMLDoc.getElementById("BRegionId").Value = "11"

'HTMLDoc.All.RegionId.Value = "11"   <<< THIS CAN FILL IN THE DROPDOWN 
 BUT NO REACTION
```

Comment: Have corrected up the code as you have suggested - Thank you :)

Comment: I am still have problems with my drop down box issue. Everything else is working fine.
Maybe can someone guide me to just one challenge. To make the selected dropdown box just drop down only. That is imitate me just clicking on the down arrow. Not selecting anything, just dropping the box down so I can see the selections available to me.
Maybe I can move forward from that if it can be achieved?